# Type error with strings converted as Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I want to create a new column `"HQ_LOC"` in the `excel` dataframe, that takes as a value the strings `j` from `wharton['conm']`

```
xls = excel[(excel['prowess_compustat_h1b'] == 1) | (excel['compustat_h1b'] == 1)]

excel['HQ_LOC'] = pd.Series([])
for name in xls["coname"]:
    for j in wharton['conm']:
        if name == j:
            j
            excel['HQ_LOC'].append(j)
```

but when I run the code above, the following error comes up, even though I converted the `excel['HQ_LOC']` to a Pandas Series

`TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explained, you cann't append str type to series type. To do what you want, you could use:

```py
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.DataFrame({'coname': ['lama', 'cow', 'lama', 'beetle', 'lama', 'hippo']})
wharton = pd.DataFrame({'conm': ['lama', 'hippo', 'tiger']})


excel = pd.DataFrame()

excel['HQ_LOC'] = wharton['conm'][wharton['conm'].isin(xls['coname'])]
```

```
# print(excel)

  HQ_LOC
0   lama
1  hippo
```

- `wharton['conm'].isin(xls['coname'])`

[pandas.Series.isin(values)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) checks whether elements in Series are contained in *values*. It return a boolean Series showing whether each element in the Series matches an element in the passed sequence of *values* exactly.

- `wharton['conm'][wharton['conm'].isin(xls['coname'])]` indexes `wharton['conm']` with boolean array, which keeps the value corresponding with true.